# I add audioplayers 0.19.1 package from pub dev but when I run pub get, I face the Error , Cannot create link, I don't know what happened

Tags: flutter

Here is the Error I face

```
Cannot create link, path = 'C:\flutter\.pub cache\_temp\dir627f91b4\ios\Classes\AudioplayersPlugin.h' (OS Error: A required privilege is not held by the client.
, errno = 1314)
pub get failed (66; , errno = 1314))
```

Comment: Please provide information about the flutter version, you are using?

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens for permission issue. So you just need to run Command Prompt in administrator and then type

```
cd folderpath
```

after that you can run pub get

```
pub get
```

This will be fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

running "vs code" (or what ever the IDE you use). ***run as admin*** solved my problem. and do what you always do in the terminal run command: `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 0):

Audioplayers have been depricated use just_audio

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).